# Python - find a substring in string and record position of substrings in a tuple

Tags: python

I am getting the below error when I check this function.  I am very close, but not understanding why the loop continues after reaching the end of the text.  How do I get it to stop searching for the substring after it has reached the end of the string to search?

Error:
The call findall('how now brown cow', 'ow') returns (1, 5, 10, 15, -1, 1, 5, 10, 15, -1, 1, 5, 10, 15, -1, 1, 5), not (1, 5, 10, 15).

Note - I have searched through the similar problems here in stack overflow, but do not see anything that is helping me resolve this using the method I have prepared so far.  Please advise.  Greatly appreciated for this newbie!!  :)

```
def findall(text,sub):
    """
    Returns the tuple of all positions of substring sub in text.
    
    If sub does not appears anywhere in text, this function returns the 
    empty tuple ().
    
    Examples:
        findall('how now brown cow','ow') returns (1, 5, 10, 15)
        findall('how now brown cow','cat') returns ()
        findall('jeeepeeer','ee') returns (1,2,5,6)
    
    Parameter text: The text to search
    Precondition: text is a string
    
    Parameter sub: The substring to search for
    Precondition: sub is a nonempty string
    """
    result = ()
    x = 0
    pos = 0
    
    for x in range(len(text)):
        if sub in text:    
            # find pos of sub in text starting from pos in text
            pos = introcs.find_str(text,sub,pos)
            # record result
            result = result + (pos,)
            # increase accumulator by 1 to find next pos of sub in text
            pos = pos + 1
        else:
            # when sub is not present in text
            result = ()     

    return result
```

Comment: `if sub in text:` this is going to be true regardless of what `x` is if the substring `sub` is somewhere in `text`. Notice how the number of positions returned is equal to the number of characters in the string.

Comment: Right.  The `for` loop is pointless (note how you never use `x`?).  Just do a `while True` forget about `if sub in text`, and break as soon as `introcs.find_str(text,sub,pos)` returns -1.

Comment: You haven't explained your method, but I'm quite sure that the code you wrote does not match what you thought you were doing.  Your `if` condition is a constant within the loop.  You use an undocumented function `find_str`.  You have a `for` loop over the positions in the string (17), but you seem surprised that you have 17 elements in your output.  Please do the expected debugging trace and update your post.

Comment: Your loop should be a `while any of the string is left`, not an iteration.  Your logic keeps cycling through the string until you've made 17 searches.

Comment: @someguy:  

hmm, yes, I see that.  I still do not understand why it is not stopping after (1,5,10,15) in the example findall('how now brown cow', 'ow') .

Comment: Because `len(text)` is `17`, you told it to loop 17 times, and it has accordingly given you 17 values in a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursive

```py
def findall(text,sub,list1=[],l=0):
    try:
        a = text.index(sub)
    except:
        return list1
    list1.append(a+l)
    l+=1+a
    return findall(text[a+1:], sub, list1,l)



text = 'aascfvbscaaasc'
sub = 'a'
b=findall(text,sub)
print(text)
print(b)
# [0, 1, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are iterating equal to the number of characters in your string. If you want to simply end upon a condition you can go

```py
    if pos >= len(text):
        break
```

but I don't think this is the best idea. You seem to ignore `x`, which is your position according to your loop statement. If you want something with a more dynamic position you might consider:

```py
pos = 0
while pos < len(text):
    # do your current logic
```

Still, this seems arduous. A two-liner compact version that is less optimized but do everything you want would look like this:

```py
def findall(text,sub):
    result = (text.find(sub, x) for x in range(len(text)))
    return tuple(sorted(set(i for i in result if i > -1)))
```

Another, more advanced, option would be to write your own custom iterator (not actually that hard) and could be used for either your solution, if you want it as a for loop over a while loop, or for optimizing my two-liner:

```py
class PositionBySubIterator:
    def __init__(self, text, sub):
        """
        Initialize.
        """
        self.pos = 0
        self.text = text
        self.sub = sub
    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Makes it an iterator. Resets.
        """
        self.pos = 0
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        """
        Makes it an iterable. Determines the variable for each iteration.
        """
        new_pos = self.text.find(self.sub, self.pos)
        self.pos = new_pos + 1
        if new_pos == -1 or new_pos > len(self.text):
            raise StopIteration
        return new_pos
```

then use:

```py
def findall(text,sub):
    return tuple(i for i in PositionBySubIterator(text, sub))
```